# Can I autologin a specific user on a specific VT, but still have other login shells running?

Tags: login, automation, intel-vt-x

I'm running a linux system with Ubuntu Karmic on it, and I use it to run a webcam and a program that continuously outputs on the console.

Is there any way I can force a user to login on VT2, and then switch VTs to VT2, but still have other login consoles running so I can hook a keyboard up to it and CTRL-ALT-F# to get to another terminal?

I have a feeling this needs to go in my rc.local file, but nothing in the login manpage seems to suggest it can do what I want it to do.

If there is no way to login a user on the vt, launching the program directly on a specific VT will work as well, since the user's shell in /etc/passwd is set to the program anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to do it with Upstart. I needed to edit `/etc/event.d/tty2` to change the exec line to point to `getty -n -l my_program 38400 tty2`, then I needed to edit `rc.local` to contain the line `chvt 2`, and remove GDM from my startup list so the chvt line would work.